# Xcode 10.0 OpenCV Cpp project does not read NSCameraDescription from info.plist

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, xcode10

[image: won't open camera]

I have already added a info.plist file, but it just wont let me use the webcam.I am in a fix as I have already tried editing the info.plist as a source file. Correct me if I am missing something. Also linked the info.plist to the plist for the app in general settings. Am I missing something? Link the the error is given in the blue highlighted section

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `Privacy - Camera Usage Description` in `Info.plist`, not `NSCameraDescription`.

Comment: Yeah. It wouldn't work. I have Mojave and now upgraded to XCode 10.0.1. Still wouldn't work after trying your way.